# Output file using ISQL

Tags: interbase, isql

Already I have a ISQL script working with Interbase that works with output into csv and I want to do the same thing to another type, but is not for example  the first code works and it works . But the second one using Join statement is only working in the sql window, but could not output it.

Working :

```
OUTPUT TESTING1.csv FORMAT ASCII DELIMITED BY ';' QUOTE '';
Select * from aircraft;
OUTPUT;
```

Not working :

```
 OUTPUT TESTING1.csv FORMAT ASCII DELIMITED BY ';' QUOTE '';
      SELECT * FROM aircraft 
        Join Operation ON aircraft.AC_ID = Operation.ac_ID
    OUTPUT;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now realise that I need to put the semi colon after the join statement:

```
OUTPUT TESTING1.csv FORMAT ASCII DELIMITED BY ';' QUOTE '';
    SELECT * FROM aircraft 
            Join Operation ON aircraft.AC_ID = Operation.ac_ID;

        OUTPUT;
```